# C - Array of pointers to Arrays

Tags: c

OK, I've written it into a single function that you can copy and paste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define OBS_TYPE_MAX 10

typedef struct obsStruct
{
    float   *obsArray[OBS_TYPE_MAX];    // Array of pointers to obs arrays
    uint32_t obsEnable;                 // which obsArray pointers are in use
} obs_struct_t;

static const obs_struct_t OBS_INIT = {
    .obsArray = {},
    .obsEnable = 0
};

static obs_struct_t  my_obs_s;


static void register_obs(int obsType, float obs[]) {
    printf("Add Obs[%d] to Mailbox\n", obsType);
    // set stuff
    my_obs_s.obsEnable |= (uint32_t) 1 << obsType;
    my_obs_s.obsArray[obsType] = obs;

    // check stuff
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("array[%d][%d] = %02f\n", obsType, i, *(my_obs_s.obsArray[obsType] + i));
    }
}


int main() {
    my_obs_s = OBS_INIT; // init
    
    float array1[5] = {0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1};
    register_obs(1, array1);
    
    float array3[5] = {0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3};
    register_obs(3, array3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Expected Behaviour

I want to define an observation array in a task and fill it up with stuff. Then I want to create a central variable which will 'register' the existence of the array and hold a pointer to the observation array.

So for example, after the above code, bits 1 and 3 would be set in obsEnable. And I should be able to grab the observation arrays based on the addresses in the obsArray[] array.

Update on my previous comment. This does seem to work in a playground. But it causes a GME (Guru Meditation Error) in the embedded environment with the full code.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought I had. To test, just lump main, task1 and task2 into main.

Comment: @EricPostpischil could you please not vote to close my question. It's a genuine question on an aspect of C programming that is confusing. What about it is not good enough for you?

Comment: The expectation for reproducing the example is that anyone could copy-and-paste the code verbatim into a text editor, save it to a file, and compile it, and it would compile, run and demonstrate the problem at hand.  The posted code doesn't meet that criterion because it has no `main()` function defined, among other things.

Comment: When you mention "task1" and "task 2", do you have multiple threads? Can the threads access the structures and data members simultaneously? How do you protect against data-races?

Comment: What exactly doesn't "work"? What is 'GME'? [mre] example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/q59Pcof7h) unable to reproduce any unexpected behavior.

Comment: On an unrelated note, instead of `(uint32_t) 1` you can write `1u`.

Comment: Also, if you only have one single `obs_struct_t` structure object (`my_obs_s`) why the need to do separate initialization of that structure? Why can't you initialize it to the default values as done for `OBS_INIT`, and then just not use `OBS_INIT` and the assignment?

Comment: And instead of explicit pointer arithmetic with e.g. `*(my_obs_s.obsArray[obsType] + i)`, use normal array syntax `my_obs_s.obsArray[obsType][i]`. That's much clearer.

Comment: And you should probably create a semantically named macro for the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `5`. And add check to make sure you don't go out of bounds of `obsArray`.

Comment: My crystal ball suggests a couple of likely causes: 1) the static variable is defined in a header used by multiple translation units; 2) the arrays are local variables that go out of scope after being registered. The `ret = ...` does not line up with the fact that `register_obs` is a void function. What's going on there? Maybe we're looking at #2 (https://godbolt.org/z/aTbxejcPq)

Comment: Thanks for the hints on formatting etc. A lot of that is just quick and dirty - I.e. replacing magic numbers so I don't have to pull defines from all over the project.

Comment: Well done stackoverflow community. Another question closed by the pedant army.

Comment: You now have a minimal example, which is good, but is it possible to *replicate* the actual behavior (which you don't tell us about)? What is a "Guru Meditation Error"? What "guru" gives you that error? I doubt you run this on a system where [that error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Meditation) originated from (which is long obsolete, but still a favorite of mine). What actually happens when you build and run the program?

Comment: @monkey Before you go on a passive aggressive criticism spree, consider the feedback and comments you received here from people who have spent thousands of hours debugging code. I already put together an example that's effectively what you are now showing, and there's nothing wrong with it. Show us the results of testing the _actual_ example that you posted. If you cannot reproduce the problem, your example is not representative of the program you're testing. Note that if your question can be reopened if it meets the requirements of a testable issue.

Comment: On another unrelated topic, the initialization `.obsArray = {}` is not valid in current C. It will be in the still not published C23 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But I used the following command to compile with no error:`gcc -std=c99 ...`. Does this mean it's a GNU provided feature but not in ISO?

Comment: @LiuYuan use `-pedantic` for ISO conformance.

Comment: As for ways to help you [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your actual code, roll back commits, comment out or even remove code, bit by bit until it works again. Then add one ***tiny*** little bit of code back, build and test. Continue until you get the error again. Then you can isolate the last thing you added and try to create a proper [mre] using that information. Or use a debugger to help you figure out why that last bit of code gives you the problem.

Comment: @paddy Message received. But I think this perfectly illustrates a point that seems lost on the minimum rep. example brigade. By simplifying and condensing the code, I have obscured the error that brought me here in the first place. The reductive fascination with working in a sandbox has rendered the question useless. But whatever. You lot, crack on.

Comment: That's actually the point of a MRE. If you cannot reproduce the error by working backwards, then you work forwards by adding stuff in until you get there. The fact that you can't reproduce tells you something in and of itself. Your original question mentioned next to nothing about the environment, hardware, compiler, structure of the code, or the libraries it uses. How on earth can you expect to receive an accurate answer when you're the only one with any of the relevant information?

Comment: Not really useless... It tells us that the error isn't in the original code you showed us. Perhaps it might *manifest* in that code (but since you haven't given us anything like a debugger callback trace, that's impossible for us to say anything about) but the actual problem might be somewhere else. One of the problem with *undefined behavior* is that sometimes it seems to work, sometimes it causes direct crashes, and sometimes it makes other seemingly unrelated code misbehave. So you have already yourself proved that `register_obs` is not at fault, which is one of the purposes of a [mre].

Comment: @monkey With the existing code you provided, I coded, ran and passed your test case. I even implemented a passible way to print the arrays you put into `my_obs_s`. I mean, I ran your code and it works fine on my platform. What really confuses you may be your "playground" but not the code itself, so maybe you can show more detail about it

Comment: @paddy. Again, you make a very good point. In my defence, I was trying to retain as much of the original code intact, and indicating where chunks run in different tasks. But as you say, it's impossible to share all relevant info without posting the entire project. Look, I 100% hear what you're saying. It would just be great if there was more than 100 nanoseconds between critical feedback and question closed. We're all here because we want to learn or enjoy solving puzzles.

Comment: Lets start over with one of the simpler questions from @paddy: Is the variable `my_obs_s` *defined* in a header file, that is included by multiple source files? If the answer is "yes" then please learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)); There will then be multiple `my_obs_s` objects, one for each source file where you include the header file. If on the other hand the answer is "no" then we can continue to dive deeper.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the level of engagement in the comments section, it's clear we are a community of problem solvers. But when you leave so many open questions, and do not actually respond to the most relevant of the feedback, what remains is a poorly specified problem that invites speculation, extensive discussion, and is just not how Stack Overflow works. "100 nanoseconds" is an emotional response born of your frustration. The question hung around for about half an hour before being closed, with none of the important requests for clarification addressed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the full code, there is actually a constructor function in a .c file. And the variable my_obs_s is actually implemented as a 1 deep queue, modified only inside a semaphore. I really did go out of my way to produce a MRE. Perhaps too far. Perhaps I need to repost this question with the native detail intact, accept that the target audience will be 1%. Lesson learned for me.

Comment: Thank you community for your engagement. Credit where it is due! Sorry I was not able to adequately describe the puzzle.

Comment: I just wanna point out that professionals frequently use this same MRE debugging technique to investigate and isolate issues. While it's not always possible, it's extremely helpful in ruling-out potential causes. Embedded can be extra challenging, and there are sometimes environmental issues at play. That's a hunting exercise. Perhaps [this](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/fatal-errors.html#gdb-stub) can help, assuming you are on ESP32... If you can get some post-mortem debugging going, you'll be much better equipped to delve into the on-device issue.

Comment: Don't be afraid of the closed question, this is not carved in stone. [Edit] your question satisfyingly, and the community will reopen your question. Then most probably it will receive at least one answer. Currently your [mre] looks OK and does not expose a crash. You might also want to add the details of that specific GME (with a background in the 80s home computer scene, I know that a Guru Meditation designates a crash; it was invented by the Amiga developers).